# How to call a submit handler in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to call my function when I click on my submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="bfe-form" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <label>Input Url</label>
    <input name="url" type="text" value="">
    <input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  getContent();
}

function getContent() {
  $content = file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
  return $content;
}
?>
```

But I get nothing my php just won't be executed.

Comment: If the form was submitted to this code, it should work fine

Comment: If you mean that I clicked the button. Yes.

Comment: Is it `.php` or `.html` file? Does your webserver process php correctly?

Comment: Please work through some of the millions of "getting started with basic php" tutorials out there on the internet. There is little sense in us repeating all those basics here. You have to use the information that already exists.

Comment: It is a .php file and yes my webserver process php correctly.

Comment: try changing this line     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: See what return $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['uplFile']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME); ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Submit button should be type=submit instead of button.

it will look like this!

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I'm assuming this page is index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Instead of use type button use type submit